# What is the efficiency of python's list slicing?

Tags: python, big-o, slice

I am wondering what is the efficiency of slicing lists in python?

For Example:

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newList = myList[1:4]
```

I'm looking for big-O notation (e.g. `O(n)`).

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by efficiency? Exec time? Complexity? (o(n) o(log(n)) etc...)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to say Big-O notation, so yeah like O(n) etc etc @smagnan

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `O(n)` for `list`s, and most sequence types, as slicing for most types performs a shallow copy, it doesn't make views of the original data.

For some types, like `memoryview`, Python 3's `range`, or third-party types like `numpy` arrays, slicing makes views, not copies, so the cost is `O(1)`, since constructing the view has identical cost regardless of the size of the view. The downside is that this can keep huge allocations alive because a single view exists on a small part of the allocation; this flaw is *why* most built-in types use a copying strategy instead of a view strategy.